# CS0103 error in ForEachAsync or FirstOfDefault

Tags: c#

I have following code:

```
private readonly Dictionary<int, string> _categoriesDictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();

private void CreateCategoriesHelper()
{
    var categories = _appDbContext.Categories;

    foreach (var category in categories)
    {
       _categoriesDictionary.Add(category.Id, category.CategoryName);
    }
}
```

When I change it to:

```
_appDbContext.Categories.ForEachAsync(c => _categoriesDictionary.Add(c.Id, c.CategoryName)));
```

I'm faced with

> CS0103: The name 'c' does not exist in the current context.

Wherever else I created function with lambda like `something => something.Id == x` it is ok.

Comment: How is `ForEachAsync` defined? That's not part of .NET Framework, is it?

Comment: is a part of .net i check all my controller now doesnt work with the same error when im using FirstOrDefault method

Comment: Oh I found it, it's part of EF6.

Comment: Yes it is part of EF6, the QueryableExtensions class.

Comment: Are you awaiting the call properly? Can you actually show the code you are using that is **not** working?

Comment: If that's the *only* change you're making, be aware that `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` is *not* safe for parallel access.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Only the actual item querying from the database is asynchronous; `ForEachAsync` uses an async enumerator under the hood. There is no parallel access happening to the dictionary (at least not from `ForEachAsync`, though you could of course access it while the task is still running)